# The NDA restrict employment information & company size

Tags: employment-agreement

The NDA states I cannot disclose company size or employment information of both a personal and operating nature except to authorized employees or agents of the company.

Seems restrictive as company size is easily found and the employment seems to keep me from listing on my resume that I worked for them.

OR am I miss reading the sentence,  this a Canadian company

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you're asking here. And anyway, it sounds like this would be a legal question, which is not on topic for this site.

Answer (score 2):

> Seems restrictive

It is restrictive. That's the whole point of NDAs - to be restrictive.

From what you have written, you can list the fact that you were employed by this company, without writing anything about the size of the company.

If company size is as easy to discern as yo indicate, then anyone who is interested can find it, without your need to include the number on your resume.

I think you have misread the statement - but consult your attorney for a legal opinion, if it's important to you.